# How to clone a windows xp recovery partition

Tags: clone

Its all in the question. The partition is on a slave drive.

Bob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clone it? You can boot a Rescue Is Possible Linux disk and image with Partimage or DD it to another drive.

Are you looking to back it up, or literally move it to another drive, or...? You don't mention if this is to back up the data or migrate it. If you make a straight clone, you may have issues with drive geometry mismatch.

You can also try Ghost or Acronis TruImage (think that's the name...look up clone acronis on google). There's also Ghost for Linux (g4u).

Those are options coming right off the top of my head...

Comment: Thanks Bart, Its been a couple of years since I looked. I'm going to download a Knoppix Live CD and use dd or dd_rescue.